# Has anyone set up Google Analytics for a public site?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, google-analytics

We are already utilizing some of the general traffic tracking with Google Analytics on a public facing internet site, but we may want to move into utilizing more of the Google Webmaster Tools.  To do that means running through the verification process, by adding a coded page to our general content, as well as adding more code to our pages for hidden tags and content metadata.

Is anyone utilizing Google Analytics to review traffic to a site?  Any roadblocks that might be good to know, or things that just won't work?  So far we've been ok with the initial tracking, and even utilizing the URL codes on redirects but if we want more it looks like more work on the content pages and I'd like to gauge how that will go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've got Google Analytics on one of our internal 2007 web applications.  We've got the code embedded on the master page as well as creating some custom events to track. This isn't deep analytics in our scenario as the site is pretty small, but it does let us know what information is being utilized.

The upshot of this is that it works better than auditing. Analyzing audit logs is painful as it loads everything that is hit when someone is navigating the site, like every CSS, img, and js reference repeatedly.  No large audit database to worry about either.

Comment: We have the same, it does work well since we can also run reports outside of SharePoint and not worry about the data in our systems.  Do you use the Webmaster Tools at all?

Comment: I did briefly for a non SP public facing blog, but not in this internal SP site.